# Javascript parse JSON data into multiple variables storing separate records in memory

Tags: javascript, json, angular, reactjs

I have used JSON stringify and JSON Parse etc..., but I'm having trouble with finding /figuring how how to split up my JSON result into multiple variables.

Issue:  I have a JSON result with 2 to many results (sections, pages etc...) 
Goal :  To store each result /row into its own variable.

Example of FULL unparsed JSON result:

```
{
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page1",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "question1"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "page2",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "checkbox",
     "name": "question2",
     "choices": [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3"
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

In the example, notice that `"name": "page1"` and `page2` are the clear separators, I could end up having them calling SectionA , SectionB etc..  but that shouldn't be important.

1. I need to store them separately
2. I also need to maintain that complete JSON structure

example of what i want to do with it

```
var page1 =
{
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page1",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "question1"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

2nd one:

```
var page2 =
{
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page2",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "checkbox",
     "name": "question2",
     "choices": [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3"
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Notice that not only is it broken apart, but the main part I want to have maintained in the variable  `"pages: [`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operation would do it.

Afterwards you can use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) to capture your result into separate variables:

```js
const data = {
  "pages": [{
      "name": "page1",
      "elements": [{
        "type": "text",
        "name": "question1"
      }]
    },
    {
      "name": "page2",
      "elements": [{
        "type": "checkbox",
        "name": "question2",
        "choices": [
          "item1",
          "item2",
          "item3"
        ]
      }]
    }
  ]
};

const split = data.pages.map(p => ({pages: [p]}));

console.log(split);

const [page1, page2] = split;

console.log(page1);
console.log(page2);
```